# If I can't take more than one character as character variable, then what is the way to declare grade='A+'?

Tags: c, character

I can declare character A, B, C, D etc as grades. But couldn't declare 'A+'.

So, if I can't take more than one character as character variable, then what is the way to declare grade='A+'?

Comment: Use a string (`char *`), or an enum, or an int (multi-character literal) - it really depends on what you want to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a Character array is one way to "declare" Grade 'A+'. However it is not the only way to solve the problem. It depends what you want to do with your program and how you want to implement it. For example this is one way:

```
Int marks;
char normalGrade = ‘F’;  // For fail I guess
char gradeAPlus [3] = “A+”;

printf(“Enter your mark (0 to 100): ”);
scanf (“%d”, &marks);

if ((marks  <= 100) && (marks >= 0) )
{
    if (Marks >= 90)
{ 
printf (“\n Your grade is %s”, gradeAPlus); 
}
else
{
    if (marks >= 80)
    {
        normalGrade = ‘A’;
        printf (“\n Your grade is %c”, normalGrade);
    }
    else 
    {
       if (marks >= 70)
      {
        normalGrade = ‘B’;
        printf (“\n Your grade is %c”, normalGrade);
      }
      else
     {
          if (marks > = 50)
     {
        normalGrade = ‘C’;
        printf (“\n Your grade is %c”, normalGrade);
          }
          else 
        {
           normalGrade = ‘D’;
           printf (“\n Your grade is %c”, normalGrade);
        }
     }
    }
}
}
else printf (“\n That is not a valid mark!!”);
```

// There is certainly more than one way to do it

Comment: Is it possible to do without Array?

Comment: No @Felix if you look at `A+` it's not a single character. It's a collection of characters and by definition **an array is a collection of same type of data**, so you'd be requiring an array to store `A+`

Comment: Yes Felix. It is possible. For example you could use an actual string argument in the printf statement like saying printf(“\n Your grade is A+”);

Comment: This way you did not resort to actually using an array of type character with the values 'A' '+' and 'null'. Once again it depends what you want to do with your program and without being able to read your mind I cant give you the answer. If however you want to store those values for later reference in a database for example then you will need to use an array if you must absolutely use A+ as a grade. However once again there are ways around it. As long as you as a programmer can relate the mark range to a grade that is the important bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**strings**](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Strings) *(collection of characters with a null terminating character at the end, click on it to see more)* instead of characters. You can declare them this way

```
char grade[3] = "B+"; 
//one byte for 'B'
//one for '+'
//extra byte for null terminating character i.e, '\0'
```

Now, you can compare strings using the [strcmp()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) function of `string.h` header file. Here's an example of how to use it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> //to use strcmp() function

int main(void) 
{
    char grade[3] = "B+";

    //NOTE: strcmp() returns 0 if both strings sent as arguments are equal 

    if(strcmp(grade, "A+") == 0) 
        printf("garde is A+");

    else if(strcmp(grade, "B+") == 0)
        printf("garde is B+");

    else if(strcmp(grade, "C+") == 0)
        printf("garde is C+");

    return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
garde is B+
```

Comment: @Felix it's an array.

Comment: yes it's an array try looking it up here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_arrays.htm @Felix

Answer (score 1):

Well, You can use 2 characters for `A+` or you can use string in C (or C++). Strings are the arrays of characters or set of characters.

Answer (score -1):

Using arrays or strings will work, although they may need more memory space.

I would recommend using enum types...

Answer (score -1):

char is used to save only a single character (that's why the name is 'char').
To save more than one character you have to use an array of characters, what is known as string.
But in your case you can have some better solution:
like saving A+ as another special character, say '+'
And whenever you use it just check if it is '+', use as A+.

```
 if(student[2].grade == '+')
     cout<<"A+";
```